# How do I use Curb? Getting unsupported protocol error?

Tags: ruby, curl

I am having an issue performing a simple HTTP GET request using [curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb).

The code is:

```
def getHtml ()
  raw = Curl::Easy.perform(@url)
  puts raw.body_str
end
```

The error message I get when I try to run it is:

```
Curl::Err::UnsupportedProtocolError (Curl::Err::UnsupportedProtocolError)
   from /home/<Username>/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/curb-0.8.5/lib/curl/easy.rb:317:in `perform'
   from getCorpusData.rb:6:in `getHtml'
   from getCorpusData.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

The request used is:

```
'http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/x2.asp?chooser=seq&p=%5B%3Dbat%5D&w2=&wl=4&wr=4&r1=&r2=&ipos1=-select-&B7=SEARCH&showsec=y&sec1=0&sec2=0&sortBy=freq&sortByDo2=freq&minfreq1=freq&freq1=20&freq2=20&numhits=100&kh=100&groupBy=words&whatshow=raw&saveList=no&changed=&corpus=glowbe&word=&sbs=&sbs1=&sbsreg1=&sbsr=&sbsgroup=&redidID=&ownsearch=y&compared=&holder=&whatdo=seq&rand1=y&whatdo1=1&didRandom=n&minFreq=freq&s1=0&s2=0&s3=0&perc=mi' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Referer: http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/x1.asp?a=&user=&word=&k=&h=&q1=&q=&c=glowbe' -H 'Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDSQCCCACB=KKPJLDIDNPDBDHCBLFDKBKLE; ASPSESSIONIDSQDAADDB=KCGNJBIAONDCMKCLGNNHEEFM; __utma=93336079.428180068.1390938982.1390938982.1391007383.2; __utmb=93336079.1.10.1391007383; __utmc=93336079; __utmz=93336079.1391007383.2.2.utmcsr=corpus.byu.edu|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/; ii=4' -H 'Connection: keep-alive'
```

It works on  examples such as www.google.co.uk:

```
* Protocol 'http not supported or disabled in libcurl
* Closing connection -1
/home/<username>/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/curb-0.8.5/lib/curl/easy.rb:62:in `perform':    Curl::Err::UnsupportedProtocolError (Curl::Err::UnsupportedProtocolError)
from /home/<username>/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/curb-0.8.5/lib/curl/easy.rb:317:in `perform'
from getCorpusData.rb:7:in `getHtml'
from getCorpusData.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

My current method is:

```
def getHtml ()
  corpus = Curl::Easy.perform(@url) do |curl|
     curl.headers["User-Agent"] = "GibSim-0.0"
     curl.verbose = true
  end
  corpus.perform
  puts corpus.body_str + "<_____HERE"
end
```

and the current URL is:

```
 'http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/x2.asp?chooser=seq&p=%5B%3Dbat%5D&w2=&wl=4&wr=4&r1=&r2=&ipos1=-select-&B7=SEARCH&showsec=y&sec1=0&sec2=0&sortBy=freq&sortByDo2=freq&minfreq1=freq&freq1=20&freq2=20&numhits=100&kh=100&groupBy=words&whatshow=raw&saveList=no&changed=&corpus=glowbe&word=&sbs=&sbs1=&sbsreg1=&sbsr=&sbsgroup=&redidID=&ownsearch=y&compared=&holder=&whatdo=seq&rand1=y&whatdo1=1&didRandom=n&minFreq=freq&s1=0&s2=0&s3=0&perc=mi' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6'
```

I'm still not really sure what to make of it!

Comment: what is the value of `@url`?

Comment: I will add now , it is a http request with user agents etc

Comment: You could try getting some more verbose output passing in a block as shown here https://github.com/taf2/curb#additional-config

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of the [documentation](https://github.com/taf2/curb), you are only supposed to pass in the URL of the site you want to grab. If you want to pass in different headers, you can pass in a block like so

```
Curl::Easy.perform("http://www.google.co.uk") do |curl| 
  curl.headers["User-Agent"] = "myapp-0.0"
  curl.verbose = true
end
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this out and let you know !

Comment: Still not working but it seems to be an issue with my libcurl , question has been updated thanks

Answer (score 0):

The real problem was my lack of headers.

To fix this I needed to include these headers, which I discovered through the network tab on the developer tools. In Chrome this can be accessed by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and clicking on the tab marked "Network", then sending the desired request and clicking into it to see the specifics.

The headings I added are in my code below:

```
require 'curb'

def getHtml(the_url)
  corpus = Curl::Easy.new(the_url) do |curl|
    curl.headers["Accept"] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
    curl.headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip,deflate,sdch"
    curl.headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6"
    curl.enable_cookies = true
    curl.follow_location = true
    curl.http_auth_types = :basic
    curl.username = "omitted"
    curl.password = "omitted"
    curl.headers["Connection"] = "keep-alive"
    curl.headers["Cookie"] = "ASPSESSIONIDSQCCCACB=KKPJLDIDNPDBDHCBLFDKBKLE; ASPSESSIONIDSQDAADDB=KCGNJBIAONDCMKCLGNNHEEFM; ASPSESSIONIDQQCDCACA=NNJHINEBBGIAJCLLICPGGMEK; ASPSESSIONIDQSBACBCB=CCOPGJBCOLBJMFJHHBIOJEHM; ASPSESSIONIDSSBBBDCA=FJBJFFOCFCPAGJJDMINGFHNE; ASPSESSIONIDSSDDDACA=CPFPDBLDIOMAALINKEEAFHKA; ASPSESSIONIDQQBAADCA=PIKHCNHACCFNDLPBGFLAEIGH; ASPSESSIONIDSQADDBDB=LJPPAJEBADDMFNAKELPPACOL; ASPSESSIONIDSQCBADDB=BHCHBFBCOAPNIANIPEILJDMK; ASPSESSIONIDQQACBADB=BPGLCBOCABKMOJEHGMGINDFD; ASPSESSIONIDQSCBAACA=FCMHMMKDKPJNKAONBHDLAMEJ; password=; email=; __utma=93336079.428180068.1390938982.1391083358.1392043146.4; __utmc=93336079; __utmz=93336079.1391007383.2.2.utmcsr=corpus.byu.edu|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/; ii=24"
    curl.headers["Host"] = "corpus2.byu.edu"
    curl.headers["Referer"] = "http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/x1.asp?a=&user=&word=&k=&h=&q1=&q=&c=glowbe"
    curl.headers["User-Agent"] = "GibSim-0.0"
    curl.verbose = true
  end

  corpus.perform
  return corpus.body_str
end

url = "http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/x2.asp?chooser=seq&p=%5Bsolid%5D&w2=&wl=4&wr=4&r1=&r2=&ipos1=-select-&B7=SEARCH&showsec=y&sec1=0&sec2=0&sortBy=freq&sortByDo2=freq&minfreq1=freq&freq1=20&freq2=20&numhits=100&kh=100&groupBy=words&whatshow=raw&saveList=no&changed=&corpus=glowbe&word=&sbs=&sbs1=&sbsreg1=&sbsr=&sbsgroup=&redidID=&ownsearch=y&compared=&holder=&whatdo=seq&rand1=y&whatdo1=1&didRandom=n&minFreq=freq&s1=0&s2=0&s3=0&perc=mi"

puts getHtml(url)
```

I hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: While it's nice that you solved the problem, your answer won't help ANYONE else solve it. Please include the headers you added. Also describe what "the network tab on the developer tools" is and what you learned. As is, this is merely a comment, not an answer, and shouldn't be posted as an answer.

Comment: You are correct , it was also the reason I didn't mark it the answer , But I digress! Will edit the  post.